# Issue with unexpected import token with Webpack and ES6

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've tried many of the solution I can find online, but webpack still gives me an error with my imports from node modules. Any thoughts why? What am I missing?

Comment: What is `client_services`? You configured webpack to not transform files inside `/node_modules/` with babel. If you want to transform the files in `client_services` as well, you have to adjust your regex.

Comment: it's a private repository. Does webpack not work with privates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want the babel loader to be applied to `/node_modules/client_services`. Currently you are ignoring *everything* in `node_modules`:

```
exclude: /node_modules/,
```

If you want to *include* `client_services`, you could write

```
exclude: /node_modules(?!\/client_services)/
```

> Does webpack not work with privates?

Webpack does whatever you tell it to do ;)

Comment: Thanks! I've been staring at this for way too long ;)